# d3 select offset parent

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get the offsetParent value from d3.select(this) -- (this is the container).

d3.select(this) returns:

```
[Array[1]]
   0: g
     offsetParent: div#divID
```

This is from the console.log() in chrome, each row is within the previous. How do I get this offsetParent div ID?

Preferably, I would like to do something like:

```
d3.select(this).select("g").select("offsetParent").attr("id")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.select(this)` returns the d3 selection. You will have to use `d3.select(this).node()` to get the dom element.

```
 d3.select(d3.select(this).select("g").node().offsetParent).attr("id")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.